# Printing a file from a string in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, image

I have a table with two fields:

1) folder: with the folder path;

2) name: the name of png files

With php code I need to take all the complete path (example frames/1.png and frames/2.png) and with this Path I need to get the real image and insert their in an array as if they were all blobs.

at the moment I use this code but with this I have only the path and not the real image. can you help me please?

```
<?php

    require("db.php");

    session_start();

    $sql = "SELECT concat('C:/wamp/www/Tecnitalia_Optic/app/webroot/img/',folder, thumb) as    mini FROM frames ";

    $result = array();

    if ($resultdb = $mysqli->query($sql)) {

        while($record = $resultdb->fetch_assoc()) {
            array_push($result, $record);
        }   

        $resultdb->close();
    }


    //send back information to extjs
    echo json_encode(array(
        "success" => $mysqli->connect_errno == 0,
        "data" => $result
    )); 


    /* close connection */
    $mysqli->close();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
require("db.php");
session_start();
$sql = "SELECT concat('C:/wamp/www/Tecnitalia_Optic/app/webroot/img/',folder, thumb) as mini FROM frames ";
$result = array();
if ($resultdb = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
    while($record = $resultdb->fetch_assoc()) {
        array_push($result, file_get_contents($record['mini']));
    }
    $resultdb->close();
}
//send back information to extjs
echo json_encode(array(
    "success" => $mysqli->connect_errno == 0,
    "data" => $result
)); 
/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
```

See: http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.file-get-contents.php

Related question: [Displaying pictures from path in PHP from MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033489/displaying-pictures-from-path-in-php-from-mysql?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

What you are storing in the table is the entire **absolute** path to the image.

'C:/wamp/www/Tecnitalia_Optic/app/webroot/img/'

What you should do instead, is to just store the **relative** path from where you PHP script is located. So, if your PHP script is in the webroot folder, the path would be just:

'img/'

With this the result should provide you the output of: 'img/folder/thumb.png'

If it doesn't work, you can debug by displaying the contents of what exactly is being returned by the $result:

```
/*echo json_encode(array(
    "success" => $mysqli->connect_errno == 0,
    "data" => $result
));*/ 

var_dump($result)
```